# How to display customer email in order grid?

Tags: order-grid, grid

I need to display customer-email and product-name in admin panel order grid
but my code return error.

Comment: Hi Ehsan and welcome to MageOverflow. To add the customer email to the grid I recommend https://github.com/magento-hackathon/GridControl the product is not that easy, because an order can have more than one product.

Comment: Problem: "my code return error" - Solution: write code without error.

Answer (score 2):

How to add products to the order grid is out of scope for an answer here but there are extensions that already to this quite well.

I can recommend this one: http://www.xtento.com/magento-extensions/enhanced-order-grid.html

I am not affiliated with the vendor, but used it for a project, it was easy to integrate and the code quality was okay.

Answer (score 1):

Declare a Module:

```
app/etc/modules/Namespace_Module.xml
```

Module declaration:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Namespace_Module>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
            <depends>
                <Mage_Adminhtml />
            </depends>
        </Namespace_Module>
    </modules>
</config>
```

Create module directory:

```
app/code/local/Namespace/Module
```

Create config file:

```
app/code/local/Namespace/Module/etc/config.xml
```

You will need to rewrite the Sales Order Grid block in the admin.  You will also need to alter the collection to add customer emails to the collection.

Config:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <global>
        <blocks>
            <adminhtml>
                <rewrite>
                    <sales_order_grid>Namespace_Module_Block_Adminhtml_Sales_Order_Grid</sales_order_grid>
                </rewrite>
            </adminhtml>
        </blocks>
        <events>
            <sales_order_grid_collection_load_before>
                <observers>
                    <namespace_module>
                        <type>model</type>
                        <class>Namespace_Module_Model_Observer</class>
                        <method>salesOrderGridCollectionLoadBefore</method>
                    </namespace_module>
                </observers>
            </sales_order_grid_collection_load_before>
        </events>
    </global>
</config>
```

Now create the observer to alter the collection:

```
app/code/local/Namespace/Module/Model/Observer.php
```

Do a join of the collection before it is loaded:

```
<?php

class Namespace_Module_Model_Observer {

   public function salesOrderGridCollectionLoadBefore(Varien_Event_Observer $observer) {

       /** @var Mage_Sales_Model_Resource_Order_Grid_Collection $collection */
       $collection = $observer->getEvent()->getOrderGridCollection();

       $collection->getSelect()->join(
           array('customer_table' => $collection->getTable('customer/entity')),
           'main_table.customer_id = customer_table.entity_id',
           'email'
       );
   }
}
```

Rewrite the Grid block class to add a column:

```
app/code/local/Namespace/Module/Block/Adminhtml/Sales/Order/Grid.php
```

Block Class:

```
<?php

class Namespace_Module_Block_Adminhtml_Sales_Order_Grid extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Sales_Order_Grid {


    protected function _prepareColumns() {

        $this->addColumnAfter('customer_email', array(
                'header' => Mage::helper('customer')->__('Customer Email'),
                'index' => 'email',
                'type' => 'text',
                'width' => '100px',
        ), 'created_at');

        return parent::_prepareColumns();
    }

}
```

Now you will see the email of the customer who placed the order.

Products is a much different beast, but this gets you halfway there :)

Comment: Apparently it's not out of scope ;)